# transfer ether from contract to another contract

Tags: contract-development, transactions, address.transfer

Have code like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Forwarder {
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => uint256) public stored;

    function Forwarder () public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function () public payable {
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function transfer (address contractAddress) public {
        require (stored[msg.sender] > 0);
        contractAddress.transfer(stored[msg.sender]);       
    }

    function store () public payable {
        stored[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

But i cannot use "transfer" method if i set `contractAddres = 0xSomeContractAddress`, but if it will be account address all found will be successfully sent.

What am i doing wrong?(except English skills)

Comment: How does the contract at `0xSomeContractAddress` look like?

Comment: You should show the cod of the receiver contract, also what error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because the receiving contract does not have its "default" function as payable.

You have to include at least this in the receiving contract.

```
function() payable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i know it, but thanks. There was a problem that i can not call payable function of another contract from payable function of mine.